# Magento 1.9 : Add custom options programmatically to associated products

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, addtocart, grouped-products

I have been working on showing custom options of simple product for grouped product. I am done with initial phase of allowing required custom option product and then showing it on frontend.
I have modified `checkout/cart/add` to add products with custom option to cart. This is also working fine. But I see products are being added twice to cart. Once with custom option and another one without custom option.
I have debugged `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php` . Here, `protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)` is responsible for adding product to cart. I tried adding custom option values of products from here. But couldn't succeed.

Note:- Here I am not trying to create new custom options. I just want to set the values of custom option.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your controller code and how you call it

Comment: It will be difficult to share my code. But can you explain which code is responsible for adding grouped product to cart in Magento 1??

Answer (score 1):

I have done it.

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
```

This code was adding the products again. As I was adding them with custom option. I forgot to put this in condition.
And both were working simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not mistaken,
i think you want to add custom options when product added to cart.

to add your custom option you need to do this:
call a event : catalog_product_load_after

```
<catalog_product_load_after>
    <observers>
        <some_name>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>namespace/modelname</class>
            <method>methodname</method>
        </some_name>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_load_after>
```

then in namespace/modelname/methodname

add this code:

```
$additionalOptions = array();
$additionalOptions[ ] = array(
    'label' => 'Print Method',
    'value' => $print_type,
);

$observer->getProduct()->addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
```

and if you want to update the values just call same function with different additional array values.

hope this clear your doubt. feel free to ask questions,

thank you.